# Word that means "to remove dependence"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am seeking a verb that means "to remove dependence" or something equivalent.

I am trying to describe a new, novel innovation of an object that eliminates the status quo object's dependence on direction.

The phrase in question is "[Blank]-ing directional dependence".

I am looking for a word whose definition is similar to "making independent", however, my nearly one hour long thesaurus search yielded nothing that fits quite right.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: In your phrase the word is simply “***removing***”

Comment: @Jim. That was my first thought, however, I later thought that "removing" isn't correct because dependence is a property, not an object. I did not realize that it works here. Thank you.

Comment: more cumbersome:  making *whatever* directionality-free.

Comment: Aside from *emancipate*? If you only want to replace the first word, then *removing* makes sense to me. Or *creating* if you swap the last word with *independence*.

Comment: Can you expand your model sentence? I'm thinking "obviate" might fit in some situations.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I like "obviate", it means just what I was looking for. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? @remarkl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like "obviate", it means just what I was looking for. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Done.

Definition of [obviate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obviate)

transitive verb
: to anticipate and prevent (something, such as a situation) or make (an action) unnecessary.

Example: The new medical treatment obviates the need for surgery.

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to restate your example, but "eliminating" sounds like a fine option. Unless you are looking for more dramatic portrayal of the accomplishment, á la infomercial, then using forms of abolish or vanquish. Eradicate and alleviate are also possibilities, again dependent on exact context (i.e., marketing or solely explanatory).  Remedying, unfettering evoke more of the liberation of something restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use "stripped" or "stripping" to signify the dependence is being removed? Or, is that too harsh-sounding?